# Lucene Query.java doesn't support clone() method anymore?

Tags: lucene, clone

we used to use the Query.clone() method to get a clone of the original query and do overriding of the rewrite method in the cloned query.

Now I find that the Query class is no more cloneable. Any idea why the change was made and what would be better way to accomplish the clone operation now?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the deprecation warning in 5.4, `clone` was only useful for changing boosts, so it was removed along with `setBoost` and `getBoost`.  All three were deprecated in Lucene 5.4, and removed in 6.0, or order to make queries immutable (with boosts now being handled by `BoostQuery`). See [LUCENE-6590](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-6590) for the full discussion.

I'm a bit puzzled, though. You claim you were getting a clone of a query, and then overriding the rewrite method on the resulting instance? Unless I'm missing something here, [I don't believe that is possible.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875666/overriding-a-method-in-an-instantiated-java-object) If you were doing this with a decorator, there is no reason you couldn't still do that, as you shouldn't really need to clone the query.

Comment: We didn't use boost to get clone of a query, we just used to get a query's clone and override its rewrite method to limit the expansion size in our case

Comment: @DivyaMalini Did you ever find a solution to this problem? We also clone and call ```setRewriteMethod(...)```